# Getting infinite loop overflow ONLY on linux - C

Tags: c

i've been stuck fro 6 hours at least to find ot what's wrong with my menu driven program.

Basically i made an excercise for an exam and to pass it i have to validate 2 test cases where at a specific input.txt file correspond an output.txt file

Now comes the fun part. SAME program, on Liux, with one test case it works flawessly, on the other the SAME menu code is causing never-ending menu operations like if the choice variable has always something in it. Of course on windows everything work as intended.

Anyone can help me with this? i'm getting crazy....

Edit: i run the program like this "./main < input0.txt"

It is about a library, at first you have to insert all the books and save them into a list, secondly a menu is shown asking you to search, rent or bring back a book, print the catalogue or exit if choice equals 5.

Actually the problem starts after inserting all the books into the program, the menu doesn't wait for user input and just starts to perform random actions in an infinite loop.

This is the code:

```
void menu(ptr head) {
    //Array di funzioni per gestire le prime 4 scelte: la scelta di uscita dal programma e' gestita direttamente dal ciclo
    void (*chose[4])(ptr*) = { print_catalogue, search_book, rent, bring_back };
    int scelta = 0;
    // for infinito per poter validare meglio l'input
    for (;;) {
        printf("Scegli un opzione:\n1) Stampa catalogo.\n2) Cerca.\n3) Prestito.\n4) Restituzione.\n5) Esci.\nScelta: ");
        if (scanf("%d", &scelta) != 1 || scelta < 1 || scelta > 5) {
            printf("Errore. Scelta non valida.\n");
            // clean the buffer
            scanf("%*[^\n]%*1[\n]");
        }
        else if (scelta == 5) { // devo uscire dell'intero programma
            break;
        }
        else { // ho inserito un numero valido, posso procedere
            // clean the buffer
            scanf("%*[^\n]%*1[\n]");
            (*chose[scelta - 1])(&head);
        }
    }

    // programma terminato libero la memoria
    freeList(&head);
    puts("Bye");
}
```

i'm pretty sure with debugging that the problem is the menu...

Comment: check if the files contain \r\n and not only \n: use `hd` in the command line to observe 0D 0A (\r\n),

Comment: Please show [Minimum,Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: It only contains \n, just checked....

Comment: @TonyB updated the question with more details

Comment: `the menu doesn't show up` If the `printf` output doesn't show up at least once, then the problem happens elsewhere in the code not posted, before `menu` is even called.

Comment: You may try print what remains by _scanf("%s",str)_ when _scanf("%d",&scelta)!=1_ , to see what blocks scanf

Comment: @dxiv actually I expressed the concept in a wrong way, the menu is just not waiting for user input. It performs random actions in an infinite loop

Comment: @androidexpert35 So what exactly is in `input0.txt`, and does it work any differently if you type-in the same inputs interactively?

Comment: @dxiv I can't type anything in it, the program starts to perform actions without letting me do anything. Adding a space or \n before %d doesn't fix anything, unfortunately...

Comment: you are "piping" input0.txt into your program.  So, it would be handy to know what it contains (as @dxiv requested).  All you show from your program in one function... we can only guess about the rest of the program... perhaps the problem is there.

Comment: @TonyB because that function is the only one causing problems. Seems like the variable "scelta" Always contains something and so the program never waits for use input

Comment: In never waits for input, because input0.txt provides the input.  What does input0.txt contain?

Comment: You are NOT specifically handling scanf() returning EOF, which would be returned when input0.txt has finished providing its input to your program.  From Ubuntu man page for scanf:  "The  value EOF is returned if the end of input is reached before either the first successful conversion or a matching failure occurs.   EOF  is also returned if a read error occurs, in which case the error indicator
for the stream (see ferror(3)) is set, and errno is set to indicate the error."

Comment: `// clean the buffer
            scanf("%*[^\n]%*1[\n]");` does _not_ clean the buffer if the next character is `'\n'`.  Use 2 calls:  `scanf("%*[^\n]"); scanf("%*1[\n]");`.  Who suggested `scanf("%*[^\n]%*1[\n]");`?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I found it somewhere here on the forum and it always worked perfectly

Comment: what is the definition of `ptr`?

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%*[^\n]%*1[\n]");`  this seems very odd, especially since the next iteration through the loop will execute: `if (scanf("%d", &scelta) != 1 || scelta < 1 || scelta > 5)` which the `%d` will consume/discard any leading white space, like a `'\n'

Comment: regarding: `printf("Errore. Scelta non valida.\n");`  Error messages should be output to `stderr` , not `stdout`.  Suggest: `fprintf( stderr, "Errore. Scelta non valida.\n");`

Comment: do I understand correctly, the `chose` is an array of function pointers?

Comment: strongly suggest clearing the `stdin` via: `int ch; while( ( ch = getchar() ) != EOF && ch != '\n'` ){;}`

Comment: in general, it is a poor idea to consume 'white space' in `stdin`  by using `stanf()`.

Answer (score 1):

At least these problems:

**Not clearing the buffer**

The following fails to consume all the text up to the `'\n'` when the first character is a `'\n'`.

```
// clean the buffer
scanf("%*[^\n]%*1[\n]");  // weak
// scanf() stop on first specifier when input is `\n`
```

Instead, use 2 calls

```
scanf("%*[^\n]");
scanf("%*1[\n]");
```

---

**Missing end-of-file detection**

When `scanf("%d", &scelta)` returns `EOF` due to end-of-file, OP's code will loop forever.  [@TonyB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62076691/getting-infinite-loop-overflow-only-on-linux-c/62077727#comment109792444_62076691)

```
 // if (scanf("%d", &scelta) != 1 || scelta < 1 || scelta > 5) {
 int cnt = scanf("%d", &scelta);
 if (cnt == EOF) break;
 if (cnt != 1 || scelta < 1 || scelta > 5) {
```

---

**Insure output is flushed**

After the print, flush - espsaily with line buffered `stdout` and print does not end with `'\n'`.

```
    printf("Scegli un opzione:\n1) Stampa catalogo.\n2) Cerca.\n3) Prestito.\n4) Restituzione.\n5) Esci.\nScelta: ");
    fflush(stdout); //Add
```

---

**Suspicion**

Problems exist in unposted `print_catalogue, search_book, rent, bring_back`.

---

Perhaps other troubles too?

Tip: Save time.  Do not use `scanf()`.  Usge `fgets()` to read a line of input into a string and then parse with `sscanf(), strtol()` etc.  Much easier to handle errant input.

Comment: I figured out the problem is the buffer never gets cleaned. The menu loops always with "Errore scelta non valida" which means that an invalid choice has been entered... The program doesn't even wait for the first input just loops itself